# Why I cannot set tab bar icon in storyboard but can use other images

Tags: objective-c, png, xcode4.5

It's simple task. Change the tabbar icon. Our designer have provided a file for that.

[image]

Notice that it's NOT how tabbar-1-nearby-normal.png looks like.

This is how it looks like.

[image]

However, other icons are doing just fine.

[image]

The size of the image is the following:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image for tab bar need to be black and white. We then latter add background for selected image and unselected image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the image and then re-adding it?  If so, how about re-adding it under a different name, or doing a clean build?

Comment: Looks like the issue is that the image is not exactly black and white or something.